# Creating a Stripe Subscription Python

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a stripe subscription and then charge the customer for that subscription. My stripe transactions are showing as "incomplete" in the dashboard, because they are not being payed.

The front-endend is creating a token using the stripe.js successfully using a pre-made stripe credit card form, but I am not sure if my back-end python code for creating the subscription and charging it is correct..

The charge should be immediate for the subscription:

> "collection_method": "charge_automatically",

```
...
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            token = request.POST['stripeToken']

            #Create Stripe Subscription Charge
            subscription = stripe.Subscription.create(
              customer=user_membership.stripe_customer_id,
              items=[
                {
                  "plan": selected_membership.stripe_plan_id,
                },
              ],
            )

            #Charge Stripe Subscription
            charge = stripe.Charge.create(
              amount=selected_membership.stripe_price,
              currency="usd",
              source=token, # obtained with Stripe.js
              description=selected_membership.description,
              receipt_email=email,
            )

            return redirect(reverse('memberships:update_transactions',
                kwargs={
                    'subscription_id': subscription.id
                }))

        except stripe.error.CardError as e:
            messages.info(request, "Oops, your card has been declined")

...
```

Comment: Which test card are you using? Seems the given card is delined. try `4242424242424242` Card

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you do not have a Card attached to your Customer, so the Subscription is not paid when you create it!

If you've already created your Customer, you should do something like this:

```
# add the token to the customer
# https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update?lang=python

stripe.Customer.modify(
  user_membership.stripe_customer_id, # cus_xxxyyyyz
  source=token # tok_xxxx or src_xxxyyy
)

# create the subscription

subscription = stripe.Subscription.create(
 customer=user_membership.stripe_customer_id,
 items=[
 {
   "plan": selected_membership.stripe_plan_id,
 },
])

# no need for a stripe.Charge.create, as stripe.Subscription.create will bill the subscription
```

Comment: I already created the customer, so this would be the correct course of action. Thank you!

Comment: This is better support than the Stripe support!

Comment: Glad this was helpful! :) For code qs, the #stripe channel on Freenode (IRC) is quite nice, a lot of developers hang out there.

Comment: I added the fix that I ended up using, I used retrieve instead. What do you think about that instead of modify?

Comment: you can use either, but the retrieve method uses two api requests (retrieve the object, call `save`), modify does it all in one

Comment: Almost 2 years later to the date, worked like a charm. Thanks!